# Add a Label over Picturebox

Tags: c#, forms, label, picturebox

I am trying to write some text over my picturebox so I thought the easiest and best thing to do is draw label over it. This is what I did:

```
PB = new PictureBox();
PB.Image = Properties.Resources.Image; 
PB.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
PB.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
PB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 30);
PB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
lblPB.Parent = PB;
lblPB.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
lblPB.Text = "Text";
Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.PB });
```

I get blank page with no PictureBoxes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not the 'best' way, but it is the easiest. The 'best' way would be to handle the `Paint` event of the PictureBox and use `e.Graphics.DrawText` to paint the text.

Comment: Have you verified that the `PictureBox` shows up by itself if you completely remove the `Label`? Are you sure your code is even being called?

Comment: Yes, I have verified and pb shows without label. Anyway I used paint event as suggested down and now am facing a problem of changing text's color, size, font and location

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While all these answers work, you should consider opting for a cleaner solution. You can instead use the picturebox's `Paint` event:

```
PB = new PictureBox();
PB.Paint += new PaintEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Text", Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
});
//... rest of your code
```

**Edit** To draw the text centered:

```
PB.Paint += new PaintEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

    string text = "Text";

    SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, Font);
    PointF locationToDraw = new PointF();
    locationToDraw.X = (PB.Width / 2) - (textSize.Width / 2);
    locationToDraw.Y = (PB.Height / 2) - (textSize.Height / 2);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, Font, Brushes.Black, locationToDraw);
});
```

Comment: Indeed, perfect, exactly what I needed, thank you man/woman :)

Comment: although, I would love to know how to edit texts font, size and location using this

Comment: Look into the DrawString method, font, size and location can all be set there. Just be careful about memory leaks (e.g. if you create a font, dispose it at some point)

Comment: You've been most helpfull, still remains one question :D
I want to center the text in my picture box... How do I do that?

I've tried using width of the graphics but don't know how...

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
lblPB.Parent = PB;
```

do

```
PB.Controls.Add(lblPB);
```

Comment: It did, but not what you want. If the PictureBox doesn't appear on the Form, something is wrong with the code that you didn't post.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this. (no use picturebox)

1. Use "Panel" control first
2. Set panel's BackgroundImage & BackgroundImageLayout (Stretch)
3. Add Label Inside panel

that's all

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the control to the `PictureBox`. So:

```
PB.Controls.Add(lblPB):
```

**EDIT:**

> I get blank page with no PictureBoxes.

You didn't see the picturebox because it has the same backcolor of the Form. So try to set BorderStyle and the BackColor. Another mistake is that probably you haven't set the location of the label. So:

```
PB.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
PB.BackColor = Color.White;
lblPB.Location = new Point(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do it. It's very simple but probably not the best one. (I'm a beginner, so I like things simple)

If I've understood your question right, you want to put the label above/on top of the pictureBox. The following line of code will do that.

```
myLabelsName.BringToFront();
```

Now, your question were already answered, but maybe this can help somebody else.