# How to save an Image from a PictureBox with added labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I add a label control to my loaded picturebox:

```
public void addTemp(int x, int y, string name)
{
    Label tempLbl = new Label();
    tempLbl.Location = new Point(x, y);
    tempLbl.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    tempLbl.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    tempLbl.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    tempLbl.AutoSize = true;

    tempLbl.Text = "P" + name;
    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(tempLbl);
}
```

How should I save this picture with my label? I tried this and it does not work:

```
  pictureBox1.Image.Save(window.save_Patch + "\\" + "test.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: you want the label on the saved picture?

Comment: Yes, I want picture with label

Comment: please add defenition of 'pictureBox1'.

Comment: You have to draw the text to Bitmap take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400943/add-a-label-over-picturebox

Comment: @new_user are you trying to add "WaterMark" on image ?